# Ошибка при запуске приложения Android

Tags: android

Создаю новый проект, любого типа... Будь то Empty, Bottom Nav., и так далее. Вылетает ошибка при запуске. Не пишу ни единой строки кода.
Ругается на метод`setContentView()`.

Код `MainActivity`(принципе смотреть не на что)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Ошибка:

```
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:406)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                            at com.guid.vorox.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
```

Comment: Ну... Покажите `build.gradle` и собственно файл разметки. Может у вас либа какая-то не подключена.

Comment: А где собственно ошибка? Она должна быть перед первой строкой приведенного трейса. А что будет, если унаследоваться от простого Активити?